# What is Faulkner's point of view in the "Address to the Graduating Class?"

Tags: william-faulkner, narrator

Here is the "Address to the Graduating Class" by Faulkner.

> Years ago, before any of you were born, a wise Frenchman said, “If
>   youth knew; if age could.” We all know what he meant: that when you
>   are young, you have the power to do anything, but you don’t know what
>   to do. Then, when you have got old and experience and observation have
>   taught you answers, you are tired, frightened; you don’t care, you
>   want to be left alone as long as you yourself are safe; you no longer
>   have the capacity or the will to grieve over any wrongs but your own.
>
> So you young men and women in this room tonight, and in thousands of
>   other rooms like this one about the earth today, have the power to
>   change the world, rid it forever of war and injustice and suffering,
>   provided you know how, know what to do. And so according to the old
>   Frenchman, since you can’t know what to do because you are young, then
>   anyone standing here with a head full of white hair, should be able to
>   tell you.
>
> But maybe this one is not as old and wise as his white hairs pretend
>   or claim. Because he can’t give you a glib answer or pattern either.
>   But he can tell you this, because he believes this. What threatens us
>   today is fear. Not the atom bomb, nor even fear of it, because if the
>   bomb fell on Oxford tonight, all it could do would be to kill us,
>   which is nothing, since in doing that, it will have robbed itself of
>   its only power over us: which is fear of it, the being afraid of it.
>   Our danger is not that. Our danger is the forces in the world today
>   which are trying to use man’s fear to rob him of his individuality,
>   his soul, trying to reduce him to an unthinking mass by fear and
>   bribery—giving him free food which he has not earned, easy and
>   valueless money which he has not worked for; the economies or
>   ideologies or political systems, communist or socialist or democratic,
>   whatever they wish to call themselves, the tyrants and the
>   politicians, American or European or Asiatic, whatever they call
>   themselves, who would reduce man to one obedient mass for their own
>   aggrandizement and power, or because they themselves are baffled and
>   afraid, afraid of, or incapable of, believing in man’s capacity for
>   courage and endurance and sacrifice.
>
> That is what we must resist, if we are to change the world for man’s
>   peace and security. It is not men in the mass who can and will save
>   Man. It is Man himself, created in the image of God so that he shall
>   have the power and the will to choose right from wrong, and so be able
>   to save himself because he is worth saving;—Man, the individual, men
>   and women, who will refuse always to be tricked or frightened or
>   bribed into surrendering, not just the right but the duty too, to
>   choose between justice and injustice, courage and cowardice, sacrifice
>   and greed, pity and self;—who will believe always not only in the
>   right of man to be free of injustice and rapacity and deception, but
>   the duty and responsibility of man to see that justice and truth and
>   pity and compassion are done.
>
> So, never be afraid. Never be afraid to raise your voice for honesty
>   and truth and compassion, against injustice and lying and greed. If
>   you, not just you in this room tonight, but in all the thousands of
>   other rooms like this one about the world today and tomorrow and next
>   week, will do this, not as a class or classes, but as individuals, men
>   and women, you will change the earth; in one generation all the
>   Napoleons and Hitlers and Caesars and Mussolinis and Stalins and all
>   the other tyrants who want power and aggrandizement, and the simple
>   politicians and time-servers who themselves are merely baffled or
>   ignorant or afraid, who have used, or are using, or hope to use, man’s
>   fear and greed for man’s enslavement, will have vanished from the face
>   of it.

Here, I see mainly two groups of words that can show the author's perspective: "we," "us" and "you," "your."
What I thought is that because this speech is motivational and gives life advice, it has the second person point of view. Because you do write a how-to-do-something or what-to-do articles by using this perspective, right?
However, my book says the perspective is the first person. Even though I see a lot in the speech was said about "us," I doubt if it's not more about "you" (since it was intended for the graduates whom the speaker could see and address; hence the word "address" in the title).
Could you help with what's wrong here?
Also, could here be two perspectives? I saw such a possibility as well though again, my book says otherwise.

Comment: What book are you referring to?

Comment: @DukeZhou It's a book on the SAT literature exam preparation. Sometimes, the explanations there are not that good at all...

Answer (score 1):

The perspective you are talking about is generally applied to narration, not oratory or addresses.  That said, this seems like it would be "2nd person".